# Create a Wind Rose Using Highcharts usind data from Mysql DB via PhP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, highcharts

I have stored my meteo data on an MySQL database; I would like to retrieve and display the wind data using the wind form.
Looking at the example of Highcharts (windrose) I noticed that the data need to be organize by cardinal direction (each wind direction is a query). 
So i created a query that supply exactly the frequency of wind directions as follow :

Speed   Heading frequency

0-5 N   154

10-15   N   81

15-20   N   91

20-30   N   35

30-40   N   1

5-10    N   100

0   NNE 1

0-5 NNE 295

10-15   NNE 48

15-20   NNE 18

20-30   NNE 6

5-10    NNE 86

0   NE  1
…
…

0-5 NNW 86

10-15   NNW 96

15-20   NNW 55

20-30   NNW 11

5-10    NNW 89

Do you have any suggestion or example on how to replace in the example below the array of data with the sql query?
Here below an extract from the example available at Highcharts
The frequency is hardcoded so that is ok.
The data section should read the query.
Any help is super welcome
thanks in advance
Giancarlo

````
<script src="../../code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div style="display:none">
    <!-- Source: http://or.water.usgs.gov/cgi-bin/grapher/graph_windrose.pl -->
    <table id="freq" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCFF">
            <th colspan="9" class="hdr">Table of Frequencies (percent)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr nowrap bgcolor="#CCCCFF">
            <th class="freq">Direction</th>
            <th class="freq">&lt; 0.5 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">0.5-2 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">2-4 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">4-6 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">6-8 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">8-10 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">&gt; 10 m/s</th>
            <th class="freq">Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr nowrap>
            <td class="dir">N</td>
            <td class="data">1.81</td>
            <td class="data">1.78</td>
            <td class="data">0.16</td>
            <td class="data">0.00</td>
            <td class="data">0.00</td>
            <td class="data">0.00</td>
            <td class="data">0.00</td>
            <td class="data">3.75</td>
        </tr>```
````

Comment: So you need to create one table header row, that lists all occurring speed intervals, and then a row for each direction, that contains - what exactly? Are the data value there supposed to be your 154, 81, 91, ...? The given table shows much lower values, with fractions. Is there some sort of conversion / additional arithmetic to be applied, or ...?

Comment: If you don't get the same number of speed intervals per directions, then you'll want to figure out the overall number of different intervals first, so that you'll know how many cells you have to generate per row. After you done that, you want to implement a basic _control break_ - for each record you iterate over, you check if the direction value is still the same, as the one of the previous record - when they differ, you know you need to create a new table row at this point.

Comment: Here is an example of the wind rose bar with the 'regular' type of data. http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/95r4owtv/ Maybe it will be easier for you to get this format of data from your data base.

Comment: The idea is to report the frequency of winds direction (N,NNW,,,,NWN) based on the wind speed bins (intervals of speed); the Data is provided in the "select query" for each cardinal point;
The  wind speed intervals will be the same for each query (0 if no wind speed was registered for a particular wind direction) to keep the consistency of the data format.

The fraction that you see in the example is the percentage of the frequency...based on the overall data (i.e. the period of one month readings).